# weird sink symptom: drips, and supply lines have no effect

Tags: faucet

Our bathroom faucet has had a slow drip for ages, so I decide to finally fix it.  (It's a one-knob faucet.)

I run the water, go underneath and turn the cold-water supply off, and the tap water suddenly turns grey for a minute -- presumably I'm dislodging a bunch of silt as I shut the supply-line.  Similarly for the other hot-water supply -- it turns grey for a minute (then clears), as I shut it off.

Mildly weird: even with both supply-lines closed and waiting several minutes, there is still dripping water, whether or not I have the sink turned on.  (And it still persists, more than a day later.)

Really weird: Not understanding the above symptom, I re-open the supply-lines.  BUT nothing happens -- no water (beyond the drip)!

At first I thought silt might have clogged the faucet, but that wouldn't explain why it drips after shutting off the supply-lines.

I have no idea what's happened.  It's like the supply-line-valves are both stuck at nearly-off?  But, I really don't think anything broke inside; when first closing the valves I had to give them a firm twist by hand, but nothing too surprising, and I didn't over-tighten them after that.

Any explanations for this behavior are welcome!

Comment: Sounds like 1) you do have a faucet leak, and 2) you also have failing valves. Even closed they let water past, and when open they're too crapped up to flow.